# What is wrong with operator"" _Bq?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, reserved-words, user-defined-literals

At [[over.literal]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal) I read, in the list of examples, that

```cpp
double operator""_Bq(long double);
```

is valid, whereas

```cpp
double operator"" _Bq(long double);
```

is ill-formed, which is apparently a consequence of the space right after `""`.

Now, from the linked page, I can easily get to [[usrlit.suffix]](http://eel.is/c++draft/usrlit.suffix) with one click and I read that

> Literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.

Good, but where do I read why `operator"" _Bq` is invalid?

I've also read the description of `user-defined-string-literal` on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), but to be honest I've found it a bit confusing.

Can anybody break that down with examples?

Comment: The comment next to the second example says why it's not allowed - `_Bq` is a reserved name per http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.1 (`_` followed by uppercase letter). Note that the example `_km` is fine.

Comment: It says "ill-formed NDR", not just "ill-formed".

Comment: @cigien, ok, but how does that change the way I can make use of it? As in, if `_Bq` is reserved, won't it be always wrong to write, say, `12.34_Bq`? Why adding a space in the declaration of `operator""_Bq` changes this?

Comment: @Enlico : The way you use the operator doesn't change, only the way it's declared

Comment: Adding a space opens it up for macro expansion. `operator""_Bq` is [one pptoken](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken), whereas `operator"" _Bq` is two pptokens, and the second one can be expanded if an implementation defines a macro with (reserved) name that is `_Bq`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, does that mean that, in the future, the standard might for instance make use of `double operatror"" _Bq(long double)` for something which will anyway _not_ map to the use of a literal like `12.34_Bq`, because this will always call `double operatror""_Bq(long double)` instead?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica _`operator""_Bq` is one pptoken, whereas `operator"" _Bq` is two pptokens_ `operator""_Bq` is two pptokens, `operator"" _Bq` is three

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - user-defined-string-literal is a single grammatical element under valid preprocessing-tokens. It's one.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica `operator""_Bq` is not an user-defined-string-literal, only `""_Bq` is

Comment: Anyway, if one follows the grammar productions and tries not to be intentionally obtuse, there is a plug in that hole @Enlico. The space breaks it up for preprocessing. It's not about the standard using `operator"" _Bq`, it's about `_Bq` being it's own "thing" lexically.

Comment: Instead of `operator"" _Bq` try `operator"" _DEBUG` and see what happens.

Comment: `""_Bq` is different from `"" _Bq` for the same reason that `double` is different from `dou ble`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"" _Bq` is a *string-literal* followed by an *identifier*, whereas `""_Bq` is a *user-defined-string-literal* which is a single, distinct preprocessing token ([[lex.pptoken]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.pptoken#ntref:user-defined-string-literal)).

As a consequence, the former is affected by macro expansion, but the latter is not:

```cpp
#define _x
int operator "" _x(char); // becomes `int operator "" (char);` which is invalid
int operator ""_x(char);  // ok
```

That aside, both forms are allowed as part of a [*literal-operator-id*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.literal#nt:literal-operator-id) and have the same meaning. However, since forming the first construct involves the use of a reserved *identifier*, it is ill-formed with no diagnostic required per [[lex.name]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.name#3) (motivation for this being that `_Bq` could be in use by the implementation as a macro).

---

That's the *intent*, anyway. The current normative wording does not actually make that difference clear enough: *user-defined-string-literal* ultimately [contains](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.ext#nt:user-defined-string-literal) an *identifier*, and [lex.name]/3 has no indication that it only applies to identifiers that are themselves preprocessing tokens. This is the subject of [CWG2521](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2521.html).